# What is the purpose of settings.xml in a maven project?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I've created a maven project in eclipse without specifying the settings.xml and it works just fine. Why do we need settings.xml? To create a cache of downloaded dependency jars or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite and define some maven settings relevant to your build environment. This especially includes proxy mirrors, default repositories, refresh settings and credentials for servers. Typically you should be able to use maven without any settings (as least if you have an unrestricted internet connection and dont want to use private servers).

Details: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Some settings (repositories) can also be specified inside the POM. The reason why this is specified in a external settings file is two-fold. On the one hand they might be specific to your machine/network or you want to keep it secret (passwords).

And on the other hand they also might affect plugins or functions running with no pom or before the pom is resolved.

Generally speaking settings.xml contain unshared stuff which you do not want to check-in or publish.

Comment: Can't we specify these settings in pom.xml?

Comment: @SandeepD expanded my answer a bit. BTW: I think it is good to read up on maven basics before using it, that can save a lot of head scratching in the long run.